# Scrape data from website from on change event using node.js

Tags: node.js, web, cheerio, scraper

I'm trying scrape data from one website. In that when page load there is drop down list and I have to select specific value from the dropdown.

For scrapping data from web I'm using `cheerio` reference link is `https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio`.

When dropdown value change then they call some `Javascript` function same like this way `https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange`.

I am able to change the dropdown value in `node.js` but value's are not change. When I scrape after change the value of the dropdown, I'm still getting default page load data.

I have search a lot on that but I didn't get any proper output. I need some `module` or `code` which is works fine with 'node.js'.

Comment: Cheerio just parses html. You need something with a javascript engine like Puppeteer or NightmareJS.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll try to use it @pguardiario

Comment: I use `NightmareJS` and it works for me. Thank you @pguardiario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just recently I used `nightmare.js` and it's good to use it. For that you have to install it.

`npm install --save nightmare`

The main thing is that which I feel , You are able to debug the code from GUI. As per your code it will show in GUI form. It's feel like automation testing.

`const Nightmare = require('nightmare')`

`const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true })`

If you want to close the GUI the just set `{show:false}`.

```
var URL = "www.example.com";
nightmare
  .goto(URL)
  .click('#btn1')
  .end()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(error => {
     console.error('Search failed:', error)
  })
```